# onclick says function is not defined while it is

Tags: javascript, html

I was getting this error in my console while trying to execute a function using the "onclick" event inside of a button. The error I got was,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    onclick http://localhost:3001/bar:1
    onclick http://localhost:3001/bar:1
```

I defined `foo` like this in the `<body>` tag followed by a `script` tag,

```
function foo(){
    fooBar();
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: Heres my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="app lol">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <title><% title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            fooBar();
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="foo()">bar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add the html file?

Comment: It will be more easy to help if you'll add html and JS full code here :)

Comment: @DanielBotnik, I have added my JS and HTML from that file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ID to your button. `onclick` is kinda buggy, because Google security features prevent you from doing so. It is even a good idea to separate JavaScript and HTML.

I usually assign an ID to a div, and `querySelector` them.

```
<div id="an-id">
  <input />
</div>
```

```
document.querySelector("#an-id").querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", foo);
```

(Put your script after the button)

Comment: Ohk, what does the querySelector method do?

Comment: @MisuteriasuKe It gets elements from where you called it (in this case, document) and it selects elements with the string you provide to it. "#" means an ID, "." means a class, if there is neither (nothing in front), it gets elements by tag name.

Comment: I now get `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null` after adding `document.querySelector("#stuff").addEventListener("click", foo);` at the starting of my `<script>`

Comment: Oh, and my button is like this. `<button id="stuff">bar</button>`

Comment: You should put your script after the button.

Comment: Putting my script after the button worked. 

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <meta name="description" content="app lol"> <script src="unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js">
</script> 
<title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script> 
function fooBar()
{
alert("hey");
}
function foo() 
{
fooBar();
} 
</script> 
<button onclick="foo()">bar</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<button id="btn" onClick="foo()">Click me </button>
<script>
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
function foo(){
btn.style.color = "red";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works!

Comment: My code looks like this too, but doesn't quite seem to work.
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="app lol">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <title><% title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function foo() {
            fooBar();
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="foo()">bar</button>
</body>
</html>```

Comment: There is no mistake in your code. But you forgot to define `fooBar()` function; rest all is working fine in your code. Try this
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en"> 
 <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
 <meta name="description" content="app lol"> 
 <script src="unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script> 
 <title></title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <script> function foo() { alert("hello") } 
 </script> 
 <button onclick="foo()">bar</button> 
 </body> 
 </html>

Comment: If this helps then mark as **answer** to help others ! Glad to help :)

Comment: I just added the fooBar() function there instead of the code that should be in place, but the code in the foo() function doesn't seem to have any issues as I have tested it before.

Comment: I found a working solution already. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Is this how your setup looks? If yes, there shouldn't be any error.

```
<script>
  function foo () {
    console.log('Foo function');
  }
</script>

<button onclick="foo()"> My Button </button>
```

Comment: Yes, this is how it looks.

Comment: try to put the above code as-is on the codepen or similar platform and see, you'll find no error.